# Unit testing with Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-boot-test

I want to test below camel route. All the example which i find online has route starting with file, where as in my case i have a spring bean method which is getting called every few minutes and finally message is transformed and moved to jms as well as audit directory.

I am clue less on write test for this route. 
All i have currently in my test case is 
`Mockito.when(tradeService.searchTransaction()).thenReturn(dataWithSingleTransaction);`

```
from("quartz2://tsTimer?cron=0/20+*+8-18+?+*+MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI+*")
.bean(TradeService.class)
.marshal()
.jacksonxml(true)
.to("jms:queue:out-test")
.to("file:data/test/audit")
.end();
```

Comment: Appropriate if you could give comments for down voting.

Comment: I don't like that downvoting without commenting either. I didn't downvote though, but I guess it's because your questions is lacking information and you don't show that you already put effort into finding the solution by yourself. Either way, I provided an answer which should give you enough hints to get the tests running with junit.

Comment: My answer can help you with first part (invoking qwartz route) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47759037/testing-camel-quartz-route/47759721#47759721

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing with Apache Camel and Spring-Boot is really easy.

Just do the following (the example below is an abstract example just to give you a hint how you can do it):

#### Write a Testclass

Use the Spring-Boot Annotations to configure the test class.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyRouteTest {
    @EndpointInject(uri = "{{sourceEndpoint}}")
    private ProducerTemplate sourceEndpoint;
    ....
    public void test() {
        // send your body to the endpoint. See other provided methods too.
        sourceEndpoint.sendBody([your input]);
    }
}
```

In the `src/test/application.properties`:
Configure your Camel-Endpoints like the source and the target:

```
sourceEndpoint=direct:myTestSource
```

#### Hints:

It's good not to hardwire your start-Endpoint in the route directly when using spring-boot but to use the `application.properties`. That way it is easier to mock your endpoints for unit tests because you can change to the `direct`-Component without changing your source code.

This means instead of:
`from("quartz2://tsTimer?cron=0/20+*+8-18+?+*+MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI+*")` 
you should write: 
`from("{{sourceEndpoint}}")`

and configure the `sourceEndpoint` in your `application.properties`:
`sourceEndpoint=quartz2://tsTimer?cron=0/20+*+8-18+?+*+MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI+*`

That way you are also able to use your route for different situations.

#### Documentation

A good documentation about how to test with spring-boot can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

For Apache Camel: http://camel.apache.org/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

@the hand of NOD Thanks for your hints, i was going into completely wrong direction. After reading your answer i was able to write the basic test and from this i think i can take it forward.

Appreciate your time, however i see that based on my route it should drop an XML file to audit directory which is not happening.

Look like intermediate steps are also getting mocked, without I specifying anything.

```
InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy - Adviced endpoint [xslt://trans.xslt] with mock endpoint [mock:xslt:trans.xslt]
INFO  o.a.c.i.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy - Adviced endpoint [file://test/data/audit/?fileName=%24%7Bheader.outFileName%7D] with mock endpoint [mock:file:test/data/audit/]
INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
```

> TradePublisherRoute.java

```
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        logger.info("TradePublisherRoute.configure() : trade-publisher started configuring camel route.");

        from("{{trade-publisher.sourceEndpoint}}")
        .doTry()
            .bean(tradeService)
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    String dateStr = Constant.dateFormatForFileName.format(new Date());
                    logger.info("this is getting executed : " + dateStr);
                    exchange.setProperty(Constant.KEY_INCOMING_XML_FILE_NAME, "REQ-" + dateStr + Constant.AUDIT_FILE_EXTENSION);
                    exchange.setProperty(Constant.KEY_OUTGOING_XML_FILE_NAME, "RESP-" + dateStr + Constant.AUDIT_FILE_EXTENSION);
                }
            })
            .marshal()
            .jacksonxml(true)
            .wireTap("{{trade-publisher.requestAuditDir}}" + "${header.inFileName}")
            .to("{{trade-publisher.xsltFile}}")
            .to("{{trade-publisher.outboundQueue}}")
            .to("{{trade-publisher.responseAuditDir}}" + "${header.outFileName}")
            .bean(txnService, "markSuccess")
        .endDoTry()
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .bean(txnService, "markFailure")
            .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "EXCEPTION: ${exception.stacktrace}")
        .end();
```

> TradePublisherRouteTest.java

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TradePublisherApplication.class)
@MockEndpoints
public class TradePublisherRouteTest {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "{{trade-publisher.outboundQueue}}")
    private MockEndpoint mockQueue;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "{{trade-publisher.sourceEndpoint}}")
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @MockBean
    TradeService tradeService;

    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {

    }

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        Transaction txn = new Transaction("TEST001", "C001", "100", "JPM", new BigDecimal(100.50), new Date(), new Date(), 1000, "P");
        transactions.add(txn);

    }

    @Test
    public void testRouteConfiguration() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(tradeService.searchTransaction()).thenReturn(new Data(transactions));
        producerTemplate.sendBody(transactions);
        mockQueue.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mockQueue.assertIsSatisfied(2000);
    }
```

Please correct me if i am doing something wrong!